# Cannot use dollar in a NAGIOS custom object variable value

Tags: nagios

With nagios, I declare a host like this :

```
define host{
    use                 aix-server
    host_name           test_passwd
    alias               test_passwd
    address             10.4.15.75
    hostgroups          aix-servers
    parents             theparent
    _LOGIN              "testlog"
    _PASSWD             "1$dollar"
}
```

Look at the custom variable _PASSWD : NAGIOS 3.0.6 does not set correctly the corresponding environment variable passed to the check script:

```
NAGIOS__HOSTPASSWD=1dollar
```

The dollar character has disappeared !

I tried many escape possibilities seen on google but it does not seems to work for the custom objects variables values :

If I tried this

```
_PASSWD             "1\\$$ \$\$ \\$\\$ \\$$ \$$ dollar"
```

The NAGIOS env var is then :

```
NAGIOS__HOSTPASSWD=1\\ \\ \\\\ \\ \ dollar
```

No dollar at all again.

So how can I put a dollar character into a value for a custom object variable ?

Answer (score 4):

Check your nagios.cfg file for the following lines:

```
illegal_object_name_chars=`~!$%^&*"|'<>?,()=
illegal_macro_output_chars=`~$^&"|'<>
```

The second line is likely your target.  Before changing either of those lines, read the docs as to why they exist and why they are set to those characters.

Answer (score 1):

Enter it as a double dollar sign:

```
_PASSWD             "1$$dollar"
```